# How can I update a bit if there are duplicate values in my SQL Server table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a pretty simple table that has some duplicate values in a certain row, when the row has duplicate values I want to update a BIT column to be 1, and 0 if there are no duplicates. The table looks like:

```
id  name    billingId  mergeable
-----------------------------------
1   David   1234        (null)
2   Bill    1234        (null) 
3   Sue     5342        (null)
4   Joe     9864        (null)
5   George  9864        (null)
6   George  9864        (null)
7   Emma    6757        (null)
```

I have tried using `COUNT(*)` and finding all the duplicate rows but I'm struggling to update the `BIT` column.

This seems like it should be easy, but using lag didn't work for me. A basic fiddle to play with is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5445a/2

I would expect the results to look like:

```
id  name    billingId  mergeable
----------------------------------
1   David   1234        1
2   Bill    1234        1 
3   Sue     5342        0
4   Joe     9864        1
5   George  9864        1
6   George  9864        1
7   Emma    6757        0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want a window function:

```
select t.*,
       (case when count(*) over (partition by billingid) > 1
             then 1 else 0
        end) as mergeable
from t;
```

If you want this in an update:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             (case when count(*) over (partition by billingid) > 1
                   then 1 else 0
              end) as new_mergeable
      from t
     )
    set mergable = new_mergeable;
```

Comment: So if I do that would I have to make this a temporary table and then update my original table in the next query to have the mergeable column be correct?

Comment: Hmm actually this returns 1 no matter what. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5445a/9

Comment: Should be ```select t.*,
       (case when count(*) over (partition by billingid) > 1
             then 1 else 0
        end) as mergeable
from users t;``` > 1 not > 0